# Non-blocking file cache (BitmapLruCache) implementation?

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I am trying to create a simple demo for the [ImageLoader](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley/+/master/src/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageLoader.java) functionality for the [Android Volley Framework](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/volley). Constructor is the following:

```
public ImageLoader(RequestQueue queue, ImageCache imageCache)
```

The problem is with the `ImageCache`. Its JavaDoc states:

> Simple cache adapter interface. If provided to the ImageLoader, it
>   will be used as an L1 cache before dispatch to Volley. Implementations
>   must not block. Implementation with an LruCache is recommended.

1. What exactly the 'Implementations must not block' in this context means?
2. Is there an example of non-blocking file cache (even non-android but "pure" java) which I can use to educate my self how to convert my existing file cache to be non-blocking?
3. If no such exist - what may be the negative implications of using my existing implementation which is (just the reading from the file):

   public byte[] get(String filename) {

   ```
   byte[] ret = null;

   if (filesCache.containsKey(filename)) {
       FileInfo fi = filesCache.get(filename);
       BufferedInputStream input;

       String path = cacheDir + "/" + fi.getStorageFilename();
       try {
           File file = new File(path);
           if (file.exists()) {
               input = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
               ret = IOUtils.toByteArray(input);
               input.close();
           } else {
               KhandroidLog.e("Cannot find file " + path);
           }
       } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
           filesCache.remove(filename);
           KhandroidLog.e("Cannot find file: " + path);
       } catch (IOException e) {
           KhandroidLog.e(e.getMessage());
       }
   }

   return ret;
   ```

   }

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> What exactly the 'Implementations must not block' in this context means?

In your case, you cannot do disk I/O.

This is a Level One (L1) cache, meaning it is designed to return in a matter of microseconds, not milliseconds or seconds. That's why they advocate `LruCache`, which is a memory cache.

> Is there an example of non-blocking file cache (even non-android but "pure" java) which I can use to educate my self how to convert my existing file cache to be non-blocking?

An L1 cache should not be a file cache.

> what may be the negative implications of using my existing implementation which is (just the reading from the file)

An L1 cache should not be a file cache.

Volley already has an integrated L2 file cache, named `DiskBasedCache`, used for caching HTTP responses. You can substitute your own implementation of `Cache` for `DiskBasedCache` if you wish, and supply that when you create your `RequestQueue`.